# how to correctly perform this sequence of matrices multiplications?

Tags: haskell, matrix

This is probably very easy but I can not seem to figure it out. I have attempted to implement a Mahalanobis distance calculation below, but are performing illegal matrix operations (`numRows a' and`numCols b' don't match). The calculation should be [1.0, 2.2] * [[0.95,-0.15] [-0.15 0.55]] * [[1.0],[2.2]], and give 2.952 as an answer. Does anybody see what I am going wrong?

```
import Numeric.Matrix as M
import Data.Maybe 

create :: [[Float]] -> Matrix Float 

create m = M.fromList m

mahalanobisDistance mu x = (transpose (minus x mu)) 
`times` (fromJust (M.inv coVarMatrix)) 
`times` (minus x mu) 
where 
    coVarMatrix = create [[1.1, 0.3], [0.3, 1.9]]

distanceW1 = mahalanobisDistance (create [[1.0], [1.0]])

distanceW2 = mahalanobisDistance (create [[1.5], [1.5]])

main = do 
    let x = create [[1.0], [2.2]]
    print $ distanceW1 x
```

Comment: use transpose maybe?

Comment: @Nikos. You mean transpose on the last (minus x mu)? I did that with same outcome.

Comment: using transposition and where exactly either on first or last vector is a matter of convention, try both, in any case this is the issue as far as i can tell

Comment: I'm a bit lost myself. Among other things, it looks like the error message doesn't match either the requirements of matrix multiplication or the code that implements the matrix multiplication.

Comment: What version of `bed-and-breakfast` are you using?

Comment: And what version of ghc are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work unmodified if you use bed-and-breakfast-0.4.3.

When I used version 0.1.2 I get index out of bounds errors.

However, to get 0.4.3 to compile using GHC 7.10.2 requires some hacking of the source. I can provide the details if you are interested.

## build instructions for 0.5

Start with version "0.5" from the github repo:

```
https://github.com/scravy/bed-and-breakfast
```

In `src/Numeric/Matrix.hs` add `foldMap` to the list of imports to hide from the Prelude:

```
-import Prelude hiding (any, all, read, map)
+import Prelude hiding (any, all, read, map, foldMap)
```

Install as usual, e.g. with stack:

```
stack init && stack install
```

or with cabal:

```
cabal install
```

Comment: please share. I think it is strange that a package should create an out of bounds error if the expression is mathematically legal. I got the same when trying to multiply parts of the expression separately.

Comment: thank you. I think I might try REPA in the morning (hMatrix doesn't work on my computer) as well, but I think that its nice for others to see your solution too.